# Python: QTableWidget scrollToItem()

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I've just started to work with python, so I run into problem. I've searched everywhere, and I've come to this: I made a simple GUI using QT-Designer. After tableWidget is filled out all I want is to automatically scroll to row 10 , which I succeeded like this:

```
for i in range(0, self.rows):
    ...filling table...
self.ui.tableWidget.scrollToItem(self.ui.tableWidget.item(10, 3), QtGui.QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
self.ui.tableWidget.scrollToItem(self.ui.tableWidget.selectRow(10), QtGui.QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
```

Problem: this doesn't work without line 3 or 4. As I said, I'm new at Python, so the good explanation or suggestion would mean a lot to me.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What "doesn't work"? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @ekhumoro Out of Eric Hulser's answer, my question is:
Why do I need this line:
`self.ui.tableWidget.selectRow(10)`

and why this line alone doesn't do anything (doesn't scroll to row 10):
`self.ui.tableWidget.scrollToItem(self.ui.tableWidget.item(10, 3), QtGui.QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this line:

```
self.ui.tableWidget.scrollToItem(self.ui.tableWidget.item(10, 3), QtGui.QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
```

Will work, because you're getting an item back as the result of doing self.ui.tableWidget.item(10, 3)

```
self.ui.tableWidget.scrollToItem(self.ui.tableWidget.selectRow(10), QtGui.QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
```

This line won't work - because what it looks like you are trying to do here is select the row in the interface, which has a None (void) value return

You have to do both calls, 1st scroll to the item, then select the row (or whichever order you want, doesn't matter the order)

```
item = self.ui.tableWidget.item(10, 3)
self.ui.tableWidget.scrollToItem(item, QtGui.QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
self.ui.tableWidget.selectRow(10)
```

In C++ you'd get an error, but in Python a void returned method will return you None, which is the same as passing a NULL pointer into the scrollToItem method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, is there another way just to scroll to that row? I don't even need it to be selected.

Comment: If you don't need it selected, you should be able to just remove the self.ui.tableWidget.selectRow(10) line.  One thing to note, you'll need to make sure this call is done once the table widget is visible, if you do it during construction, it won't have proper coordinates to scroll to yet.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thank you.
Interesting thing is that it works while table is not visible, but only with `self.ui.tableWidget.selectRow(10)`

Comment: Interesting - that call might force an update then internally that made the scroll work while the table was still loading.  Not sure - I usually do all scroll/position based operations once the table is visible.